# Missing imports after compiling gRPC .proto file for GO using GoLand

Tags: go, grpc, goland

I am trying to work out the example from a gRPC book, and I struggle to get what's wrong with what I am doing.

I have a .proto file, and I can compile it into the .pb.go stub.

I am trying to build both the client and the server, and the folders structure looks as following:
[image: Folder Structure]

I run these commands successfully and I generate the .pb.go files for both client and server, so no issue with that:

```
service % protoc -I ecommerce ecommerce/product_info.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:./ecommerce

client % protoc -I ecommerce ecommerce/product_info.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:./ecommerce
```

However, while the server's go file can resolve all the imports, the same doesn't happen for the client.

[image: the client showing unresolved imports]

Looking at the folder structure, I was expecting everything to work out (I just started this week with go and gRPC, so please be understanding).

My IDE is GoLand, I suspect there is something wrong with the paths, but I wouldn't know where to start right now.

Comment: Have you tried Sync Dependencies action (*Option/Alt+Enter* over red import statements)?

Comment: Where is the `go.mod` for your `client`? (I can see one in the `service` folder but not in `client`). If you dont have one further up the tree then you probably need to run `go mod init [module-path]` (followed by `go mod tidy`) in the `client` folder.

Comment: @Brits thanks, that was it, the missing .mod file in the client. Should put this as the answer so I can vote for it.

Comment: please consider reading this for future questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments the screenshot showed a `go.mod` in `service` but none in `client`. As goland will be running with 'Go Modules Integration' enabled it will be expecting a module (I'd highly recommend using modules!).

The simplest fix is to run `go mod init [module-path]` (followed by `go mod tidy`) in the client folder. You could also establish a module in the `backend` folder (or `productinfo` folder) and that will be shared by child folders.